# Como mudar cor do botão usando código RGB ou hexadecimal?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hexadecimal, rgb

Tenho uma aplicação WinForms e gostaria de usar cores que não se encontram nas predefinições do objeto `Color`. A título de exemplo:

Como o código se encontra:

```
this.btnLogout.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Exemplo de como eu gostaria de *setar* a cor:

```
//this.btnLogout.BackColor = this.btnLogout.setBackColor("#8003ba" ou "rgb(128, 3, 186)");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

usando `.FromArgb()`tbm é possivel controlar o canal Alfa que aceita um `int` de 0 a 255.

```
//--> ARGB o Alfa vai 0 à 255
button2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 250, 0, 100);
```

Answer (score 5):

Tem várias formas de fazer isto, uma delas é usando o método [`FromArgb`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Color_FromArgb_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) de `Color`:

```
Color.FromArgb(128, 3, 186)
```

Ou

```
Color.FromArgb(0x80, 0x03, 0xBA)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/Color.cs).